Forced string formatting to include dashes
String methods are not my strong suit, I've been trying to manipulate an input field value that needs to be 24 characters long

21 of those characters are letters or numbers (no special characters other than dash)
3 of those fields are dashes in the 3rd, 8th, and 17th place
I've got it working when 21 characters have been entered, but struggling to think through if a user adds more than 21 characters, or when a user add say, 30 characters, how do I only keep the first 21 entered & add dashes?


const caseNumberInput = document.querySelector(".theme--mobile #case_number");
caseNumberInput.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
  //get rid of all special characters other than "-"
  const value = e.target.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "");
  const length = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "").length;

  if (length === 21) {
    //if length is 21, add the dashes in the 3rd, 8th, and 17th places
    caseNumberInput.value = value.slice(0, 2)+ "-" + value.slice(2,6) + "-" + value.slice(6, 14)+ "-" + value.slice(14)
  }

  if (length >= 21) {
    //remove the dashes then add them back so I don't get multipe dashes if they are already existing / keep only 21 characters?
    let newValue = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "").toUpperCase().slice(0, 21);
    newValue.slice(0, 2)+ "-" + temp.slice(2,6) + "-" + value.slice(6, 14)+ "-" + value.slice(14);
    caseNumberInput.value = newValue
    console.log(newValue)
  }

});

//keyup to remove any special characters except "-"

caseNumberInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "")
});



What is the goal here?  Do you want to simply validate that the input is 21 numbers/letters with 3 dash separators?  Or do you want to add dashes as well?  Can you add some sample input and output to the question?

You should remove the keyup listener entirely. Filtering input as it’s given in web browsers is non-trivial and usually not worth it. (For an example of the problems, try editing some text at the start of the field.)

Hi @TimBiegeleisen the goal is to have 21 characters on every submission, with a dash appended in the 3rd, 8th, and 17th place (so total 24 with dashes on every submission)

@Ry- Thank you for the tip, I will remove.

You still haven't answered my question.  Do you need to validate only, or correct and validate?

@TimBiegeleisen correct & validate

It's usually done like this:
const caseNumberInput = document.querySelector(".theme--mobile #case_number");

caseNumberInput.addEventListener("blur", (e) => {
  // Get and sanitize input
  let value = e.target.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");

  // Keep only the first 21 characters
  value = value.slice(0, 21);

  // Add dashes in the 3rd, 8th, and 17th positions
  const formattedValue = `${value.slice(0, 2)}-${value.slice(2, 7)}-${value.slice(7, 16)}-${value.slice(16)}`;

  caseNumberInput.value = formattedValue;
});

caseNumberInput.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  // Sanitize input
  e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]/g, "");
});

That is, filter, trim the extra characters, and then insert - in the right places.
If you need to put dashes after 21 characters, you can compare value before and after slice and add the necessary number of dashes.
